# When to get rid of '-SNAPSHOT'

Tags: continuous-integration, git, maven

I'm working on a Git workflow (not git-flow) for a Java project that uses Maven and Artifactory for artifact storage. On develop and feature/* branches the version number contains '-SNAPSHOT'. It is not desirable to have release/* or master branches with '-SNAPSHOT' so I'm trying to figure out when (and how) to get rid of it.

I came up with a partial workflow, as below, but it doesn't handle removing 'SNAPSHOT':

```
                v1.0-snap    v1.0-snap
feature/a       * ---------> *
                ^            |
                |            |
                |            v
develop         *            * v1.0-snap
                v1.0-snap    |
                             |
                             v        
release/1.1        v1.0-snap * -----> *
                                    v1.1-snap
```

I came up with 2 options, but both might be wrong.

**Option 1**

```
                v1.0-snap    v1.0-snap
feature/a       * ---------> *
                ^            |
                |            |
                |            v             v1.1-snap
develop         *            * v1.0-snap  *
                v1.0-snap    |           /
                             |          /
                             v         /
release/1.1        v1.0-snap * -----> * v1.1-snap
                                       \
                                        \
                                         \
master                                    * --------> *
                                          v1.1-snap   v1.1
```

**Option 2**

```
                v1.0-snap    v1.0-snap
feature/a       * ---------> *
                ^            |
                |            |
                |            v             v1.1-snap
develop         *            * v1.0-snap  *
                v1.0-snap    |           /
                             |          /
                             v         /
release/1.1        v1.0-snap * -----> * ----- >* v1.1
                                   v1.1-snap    \
                                                 \
                                                  \
master                                             *
                                                  v1.1
```

Both options seems weird to me, though.

Is there any best practice for this kind of flow?

Comment: How is the version mapped to the release/master branch?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup.

For `feature/*` and `develop`, I use something like `18.08-SNAPSHOT` in my pom.
When we're ready to start release hardening, I'll cut a release branch (`release/18.08`) and change the version in the pom/s to `18.08`.

I'll also bump the version on develop to `18.09-SNAPSHOT`, for example.

From there, bugfix and finalise the release, merge to `master` when appropriate.

We're not properly CI/CD yet, but the issue I bumped in to with release builds was that I still needed unique builds in Artifactory.  So, at build time (for release branches) Jenkins will change the version in the pom to something like `18.08-326` (326 being build number).  It won't commit this change, but the artefact that gets built and pushed to Artifactory will be unique (`foobar-18.08-326.war`)